# Customize the GridView like in the image below

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

Please help me in customizing like in the image

[image]

Below is my grid_mainborders.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grid_two_borderselected"
        /> <!-- focused -->
    <item  android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grid_two_bordernormal"/>

    </selector>
```

Below is my grid_two_borderselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Below is my grid_two_bordernormal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Below is my GridView Item file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_mainborders">



<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewGridLangsItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_mainborders">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMaintext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="English"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSubText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="English"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAlphabet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E"
            android:textSize="38sp"
            android:padding="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I am using gridview with base adapter,
I have tried with few links but background is changing not with the corners of selected item.
Please help me on this Thanks in advance

Comment: use ``android:checkable="true"`` attribute in cardView .This will checked the clicked item with checked icon with primary color

Comment: Hi chand mohd, I have tried with android:checkable="true" but it is not working like in the image, there is no response once we click on the particular item. Where to add background in the Item xml ? I am confused.Could you please help me on this.

Comment: "but it is not working like in the image"?? what do you mean by that ..

Comment: I have added checkable attribute, UI doesn't change when clickable on Item. It display the same UI (click/unclick)